# Java JTextArea Question

Tags: java, jtextarea

I am designing an on-screen form to be filled in, and I think it makes sense to stick it together as a collection of text areas.  I note in the documentation of JTextArea that a text area can be subdivided into rows and columns, but I can't find any methods that appear to deal with placing text directly in any specific row/column cell in a text area.

Are there such methods, or is there an alternative text component that would work better for this purpose?

Thanks in advance for any insights.

John Doner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit hackish, but you could insert (row-1) newlines and (column-1) space characters before your actual content. Of course that would only work on a previously empty text area.

However, you can extend that approach so that you only insert characters if needed, and otherwise just count already existing characters. That is, to go to a row, you skip the first row-1 newlines. Then in that line, you skip the first column-1 characters.

If there aren't enough newlines or characters already in the text area, you add more at the end of the text.

However, it gets trickier if your text content contains newlines itself.

It's doable, but it's gonna be ugly.

Comment: as it turns out, I did just stick a lot of text areas together, with very narrow spacing between then so that the form on screen looks like the paper form it will replace.  The text boxes all contain one or more labels, and the user simply clicks in the proper box at the right location (some areas have more than one label for more than one type of data), and enters data.  The process of gathering these individual text lines together into a single text stream is very repetitive, so quick, and I store that string to a file.  Recalling it is likewise tedious, but repetitive.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a table, there is [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) but it is a bit  more complicated. ([Here is a tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)) Alternatively you could put your JTextAreas into a layout such as [GridLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html)

Comment: I would suggest linking to a more current version of the API.

Answer (score 0):

The row and columns values are just used to give the text area a preferred size.

I don't see the point of trying to set text at a specific row when creating a form. Generally forms would be designed with label/text field pairs, so the user know where there are entering the text.

If you text area is for output then you just add new lines when you want to display text on a different line.

Forcing a text area to be able to insert text at a given row/column is definitely not the way it was intended to be used.

I don't understand the real requirement so I can't make any other suggestions.